# Is the scientific method used in programming?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

If you have a program that's faulty, would one use a version of the scientific method to figure it out? I find myself doing things like this when I have program issues (not debugging or syntax errors).

But I haven't seen anything on the internet about the sci method in  programming. Is there a diagnostic method for computer programming in particular? If not how should one go about solving a specific issue with a complex program?

Comment: @OrifKhodjaev this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

Scientific method means empirical. Yes, all the debugging, finding problematic places, bottlenecks, bug hives etc. are all empirical, so yes, scientific method is used during all phases of software development.

One of the ways to ensure that there are (no)problems with the system is to write tests (automated experiment). There could be unit or integration tests. However, if you design your application by contract, you could decouple all modules in your system and test only directly (via "interface") related pairs of modules. And so, following principle of mathematical induction, if any two elements in a set share same behavior/property, all elements in the set do: if you write your tests well, you eventually would not be able to prove that there is a bug in your system which is cosidered the same as there are no bugs in the system.

If you use git, there is a command `git bisect` that uses binary search algorithm to help you find the commit that introduced problems.

Whatever methods you use you'll find they are all based on "experiments" and/or observations, so they follow scientific method.